# i want to remove html tags from sgml file

Tags: python, html

I have sgml files like:

```
        <DOC>
        <DATE> September 10 2017 02:45 </DATE>
        <HL> 経済は落ち込んでいます </HL>
        <TEXT>
        <p>
        それはその国にとって良い時期ではありません。
        <p>
        コミュニティは彼を愛している
        </TEXT>
        </DOC>
```

I want to remove the html tags and keep the information in new line as is. I want to do it using python.

I have tried some code but it doesnt work.

```py
import re
import os
import sys
data_dir = sys.argv [1]

    def cleanhtml(data_dir):
        cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
        cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', data_dir)
        return cleantext
```

The code runs without an error or output.

Comment: You have to call you method like `cleanhtml(data_dir)` after you have defined the method.

Comment: it looks like you are removing the html tags from your data_dir, not the actual file (if the variable names are correct)

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, it will never work correctly in all cases. Use html parser instead, for example `BeautifulSoup`:

```
data = '''<DOC>
    <DATE> September 10 2017 02:45 </DATE>
    <HL> 経済は落ち込んでいます </HL>
    <TEXT>
    <p>
    それはその国にとって良い時期ではありません。
    <p>
    コミュニティは彼を愛している
    </TEXT>
    </DOC>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
September 10 2017 02:45
経済は落ち込んでいます
それはその国にとって良い時期ではありません。
コミュニティは彼を愛している
```